# Can we scale text inside draw scope in compose?

Tags: canvas, android-jetpack-compose, scale, custom-painter, jetpack-compose-drawscope

I am creating a custom painter and want to write some text inside. I want to scale the text according to the size of the canvas.

For example, if the canvas height is x, I want my text height to be x/2.

Is it possible in jetpack compose?